How did we get to traditional size pulleys and when exactly did they become a relic of tradition?
Over time in the development of rear derailleurs brought to market, we can see most of the players going larger in tooth count most of the time, for both mainstream off-the-shelf components and also aftermarket pulley/cage upgrade/modification products. Though in recent years the high-end mod products have gotten the most attention, we also see lesser examples of the trend far earlier on various Shimano and SRAM RDs of the aughts.
It's easy to list marketing-friendly snippets of reasons why, and we have many articles and ads that do. The most commonly cited headline reason is reducing friction losses from chain articulation, and secondarily from reducing the rotation speed of the pulley. Though it's fallen out of fashion now, prior marketing materials would often cite ground clearance gains from getting to a target total capacity via a shorter cage and bigger pulleys.
Did the traditional 10t pulleys and their associated cage lengths, found on many derailleurs from the fifties to the aughts, ever make sense? Did they only make sense for certain drivetrain types, i.e. those with relatively narrow gear ranges such as golden age road racing bikes? Is the number 10 and the size of a 10t pulley simply a byproduct of what was practical in some bygone moment of plastics manufacturing technology? By large pulleys showing up everywhere today, is there some utilitarian tradeoff being foisted on everyday cyclists in favor of marginal gains, other than loss of interchangeability and ease of procurement?

Is this question approached in The Dancing Chain? I will look tomorrow. The early derailleurs had no teeth at all: I think the relative diameter for the chain must have equalled 10 teeth, or close enough. Then why was that diameter roller chosen? A standard part transferred in from another industry?

I don't think it is directly addressed by Berto in these terms. Where 10t may intrinsically make sense, or seem to aside from the issue of excess articulation per current dogma, is if your total capacity needs were such that 10t on the shortest possible cage that allowed you to route a chain through, but maybe you thought there was some kind of negative tradeoff with 8t plus making the cage longer, as in maybe someone thought 10t was the sweet spot for friction losses plus minimal cage length.

I would assume the engineers simply went for the smallest pulley size which worked. After all, going small reduces mass which is not just great for marketing but also lowers production cost (however slightly). The losses in efficiency are tiny and only really became known thanks to CeramicSpeed and their oversized pulleys. The engineers back then probably didn’t even measure drivetrain efficiency.

Also just speculation, but Shimano used 11t pulleys on their RDs for quite a long time. This coincides with the 11t small cog used on Hyperglide cassettes. I wonder if someone did some experimentation with different cog sizes and it was determined that 10 or 11 teeth is the minimum (given technologies and smoothness expectations at the time). Also, smaller RD pulleys result in less lateral play given a certain bearing clearance (did older pulleys have looser bearings?), although this is counteracted by the Centeron floating pulley system. You've asked an interesting question for sure.

Guessing - maybe the tooling for making 11T as the smallest cog somehow had efficiencies with an 11T jockey wheel at some point?  Nowdays an injection-moulded plastic jockey wheel has no connection with a metal 11T gear, but perhaps in the past?   Comment, because guess.

2.5W gain at 250W is not not much of an improvement unless you are riding competitively. You pay with a larger target for rocks and debris, and peraps a bit of weight and drag? But perhaps large pulleys will take over in the future. I'm not sure I approve of the estethics of oversized pulleys. https://velo.outsideonline.com/road/road-racing/tour-de-france-pros-are-using-oversize-rear-derailleur-pulleys-should-you/
